# Spring Boot ZooKeeper client

Tags: maven, spring-boot, apache-zookeeper, spring-cloud-zookeeper

I want to use ZooKeeper in order to synchronize my distributed services via ZooKeeper ephemeral nodes.

The idea is the following - every node in the topology on the startup will create ZooKeeper session and ephemeral nodes. On the node restart or failure, these nodes will disappear.

I'm going to implement it using Spring Boot. Right now I'm in doubt what project and Maven dependency to use in order to have ZooKeeper client autoconfiguration, be able to create ZooKeeper session on the application startup, be able to create from this client - ZooKeeper ephemeral nodes and use ZooKeeper transactions.

Right now I'm looking on [Spring Cloud Zookeeper/](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-zookeeper/) but I'm not sure is it a right one for this purpose. Could you please point me to the right Spring Boot ZooKeeper project and show the small example how to achieve that I have described above.